# ERROR: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) but when I ran `docker-compose run --no-deps app rails new . --force --database=mysql` I got the error mentioned in the question title. Below are the contents of some of my files:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /essence
COPY Gemfile /essence/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /essence/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /essence

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Configure the main process to run when running the image
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: *****
      MYSQL_USER: *****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *****
  app:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f /essence/tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_USER: *****
      DB_NAME: *****
      DB_PASSWORD: *****
      DB_HOST: *****
```

I tried about 20 different things but none of them resolved this error. Does anyone know on a first glance what could be wrong with my setup? Thank you!

Comment: have you tried running it by `ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]` as mentioned in the docs?
`

Comment: What's actually in the `entrypoint.sh` file?  You could get that error if its "shebang" line `#!/path/to/interpreter` names something that isn't in the file, or if you incorrectly have DOS line endings.  (If deleting an old pid file is necessary in Docker, that would also be a good thing to do in the entrypoint script rather than overriding the `command:` in the Compose setup.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I changed the command in docker-compose.yml to just `bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'` and docker-compose no longer threw this error. However, it did not create the files (e.g. package.json) that the tutorial said it should create. I think it's because my workdir is in external drive whereas docker app is in local mac drive. Is there a way I can create the docker image on an external drive? This is what I am trying to achieve.